# Azure Event Hub access blocked in Node-red

Tags: node.js, azure, node-red, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to connect to Azure Event Hub through Node-red to get the data I'm forwarding, but I suspect it's failing due to access issues.

The node I'm using to pull the data is the following one: 
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-eventhub-receive

[image]

As you can see in the image above it returns an error without specifying which. The tricky thing here is I'm using it in an enterprise network and I guess there are some closed ports blocking the access, but I'm unable to find which. Node-red does have internet access since I've downloaded a few nodes from the palette, so that narrows the issue to the accessibility.

I have used this same set-up in my home network without issues, so that discards any problem with Azure, the Event Hub nor the connection string.

Does anyone have a clue of what port it's going through or what may be blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

Azure event hub uses AMQP protocol to transfer messages.The Advanced Message Queueing Protocol 1.0 is a standardized framing and transfer protocol for asynchronously, securely, and reliably transferring messages between two parties. It is the primary protocol of Azure Service Bus Messaging and Azure Event Hubs. Both services also support HTTPS. The proprietary SBMP protocol that is also supported is being phased out in favor of AMQP.

Here is a short summary and a few references which should clarify the topic for outbound ports:

First of all it depends on if you use the old or the new client or if you use the rest APIs. The AMQP protocol guide actually has good guidance in the below article, under the section "Connections and Sessions":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide

Key points from above article:

•   Azure Service Bus requires the use of TLS at all times.

•   It supports connections over TCP port 5671 and over TCP port 5672. The server immediately offers a mandatory upgrade to TLS using the AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding creates a tunnel over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP 5671 connections.

•   Both modern (.Net Standard and Java) clients use AMQP, hence the above guidance applies.

•   The older .NET library has a custom, WCF based protocol that used TCP and port 9354 (called SBMP, Service Bus Messaging Protocol).

•   If you solely use our rest API you may be able to open only port 443.

**IP address white listing**

To find the right IP addresses to white list for your connections you can for example do the following. Either copy the namespace URL from the connection string or typically you can just use YourNamespaceName.servicebus.windows.net and then open a command prompt and execute: nslookup YourNamespaceName.servicebus.windows.net. The IP address returned in "Non-authoritative answer" is what you are looking for.

Please note: This IP address is static. The only point in time it would change is if we e.g. would restore the namespace on to a different cluster which is not anything we would normally do without some severe incident happening.

Hope it helps.